# Accessing list element using grep

Tags: r, list, indexing, lapply

How can I directly access a list item using a grep output?
So far, I found an indirect way that works involving unlisting both the list and the grep output:

```
list1 <- list(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"))
list2 <- list(c("GroupA", "GroupB", "GroupC"))
list.all <- c(list1,list2)
```

The following code works, but I'm looking for an alternative to unlist()

```
idx <- unlist(lapply(list.all, function(x) grepl("Group1", x)))
unlist(list.all)[idx]
```

returns "Group1" as expected.

What I am looking for syntax-wise - but doesn't work - is to access the list element directly by something like:

```
list.all[[id.index]]
```

But this obviously returns > invalid subscript type 'list'

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the elaborate answer by @Andrew, I found the probably easiest way to take his considerations on safe methods into account, while also maintaining maximum readability imho. Main credits go to @Andrew though. My answer is only for those who don't want to read through his interesting analysis. Here's my suggestion:

```
idx <- unlist(list.all) %in% "Group1"
unlist(list.all)[idx]

"Group1" "Group1" "Group1"
```

Or shorter and more elegantly with dpyr:

```
unlist(list.all) %in% "Group1" %>% unlist(list.all)[.]
```

I'm aware that this still doesn't get rid of unlist() - my initial goal - but avoids the risk to get false results by grepls' partial matches.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have done some thinking about this. Unfortunately, I have nothing simple (like what you asked for), but I have sliced this a few different ways and thought it would be good to share. Of course, you could turn any of these into a function if you want simplicity.

Also, for what it's worth, I did this as a way to teach myself how to work with matching text in lists, which is why it leans toward being a littleeee over the top (maybe).

**Data**:

```
list1 <- list(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"))
list2 <- list(c("GroupA", "GroupB", "GroupC"))

list3 <- list(rep(paste0("Group", 1:1e5), 2))
list4 <- list(rep(paste0("Group", LETTERS), ceiling(2e5 / 26)))

list.12 <- c(list1,list2)
list.34 <- c(list3,list4)
```

### Options that return a vector

**Option 1** (your option):

```
idx <- unlist(lapply(list.12, function(x) grepl("Group1", x, fixed = T)))
unlist(list.12)[idx]
[1] "Group1"
```

**Option 2**:

```
idx.list <- lapply(list.12, grepl, pattern = "Group1", fixed = TRUE)
match.list <- Map(`[`, list.12, idx.list)
unlist(match.list)
[1] "Group1"
```

**Option 3**:

```
unlist(list.12)[(grep("Group1", unlist(list.12), fixed = TRUE))]
[1] "Group1"
```

**Option 4**:

```
unlist(list.12)[(stri_detect_fixed(unlist(list.12), "Group1"))]
[1] "Group1"
```

And benchmarks for the small list:

```
Unit: microseconds
  expr    min     lq     mean  median     uq      max neval
 opt_1  7.001  8.305 153.6345  8.7790  9.668 1454.531    10
 opt_2 12.234 12.433  14.6120 13.0425 14.481   26.645    10
 opt_3  3.744  3.861   5.7395  4.0010  5.509   18.314    10
 opt_4  4.511  4.763   7.1403  5.1635  6.047   18.205    10
```

**Output for** `list.34` **for all the above options**:

```
[1] "Group1"    "Group10"   "Group11"   "Group12"   "Group13"   "Group14"  
[7] "Group15"   "Group16"   "Group17"   "Group18"   "Group19"   "Group100" 
[13] "Group101"  "Group102"  "Group103"  "Group104"  "Group105"  "Group106" 
[19] "Group107"  "Group108"  "Group109"  "Group110"  "Group111"  "Group112"
...........
[997] "Group1885" "Group1886" "Group1887" "Group1888"
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 21224 entries ]
```

And benchmarks (for what they are worth):

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 opt_1 20.28270 21.59880 24.63574 22.97677 25.07883 34.28110    10
 opt_2 15.65542 17.01358 19.29739 17.47097 18.95579 28.15225    10
 opt_3 21.87411 23.17457 25.59646 24.06683 25.01356 40.57871    10
 opt_4 31.78084 34.60584 38.84164 38.00180 42.79115 50.28889    10
```

So it looks like option 2 scaled the best with the larger data. But the output illustrates why one must be careful when using `grep`, `grepl` or other functions that use regex.

### "Safer" options that return a vector

So, I thought it may be helpful to include a few options that are "safer." And, by safer, I mean they will only match the text "Group1". They will not also match "Group11..."

**Safe option 1**:

```
unlist(list.12)[match(unlist(list.12), "Group1", nomatch = F)]
[1] "Group1"
```

**Safe option 2**:

```
unlist(list.12)[unlist(list.12) %in% "Group1"]
[1] "Group1"
```

**Safe option 3**:

```
idx.list <- lapply(list.12, grepl, pattern = "\\bGroup1\\b")
match.list <- Map(`[`, list.12, idx.list)
unlist(match.list)
[1] "Group1"
```

And benchmarks for the "safer," or exact word match, options:

```
Unit: microseconds
   expr    min     lq    mean  median     uq    max neval
 safe_1  3.063  3.124  3.9562  3.7135  4.172  7.157    10
 safe_2  2.897  3.089  5.8281  3.3700  4.436 26.729    10
 safe_3 27.978 28.564 34.1458 28.9110 30.869 75.457    10
```

**Output for** `list.34` **for all the safer options that output a vector**:

```
[1] "Group1" "Group1"
```

This output is expected because there are only two `"Group1"`'s in `list.34`

Benchmarks for `list.34` for the safer options.

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 safe_1  13.79823  14.45908  17.40700  15.07796  23.18696  23.95939    10
 safe_2  15.61516  17.61696  21.76075  21.15972  25.17552  28.91110    10
 safe_3 120.27222 125.82341 129.01684 129.11074 131.15969 141.02159    10
```

### Options that return a list

Last, I thought it may also be useful to keep the matches in list form. So, I did this a couple ways, and benchmarked them as well. Do note, options 1 and 4 return the same results, and options 2 and 3 return approx. the same results.

**List option 1**:

```
idx.list <- lapply(list.12, grepl, pattern = "\\bGroup1\\b", fixed = F)
match.list <- Map(`[`, list.12, idx.list)
match.list[lapply(match.list, length) > 0]
[[1]]
[1] "Group1"
```

Returns only matching element

**List option 2**:

```
Filter(function(x) "Group1" %in% x, list.12)
[[1]]
[1] "Group1" "Group2" "Group3"
```

Returns vector containing matching element

**List option 3**:

```
list.12[which(unlist(list.12) %in% "Group1")]
[[1]]
[1] "Group1" "Group2" "Group3"
```

Also returns vector containing matching element

**List option 4**:

```
list4_ind <- Map(`%in%`, list.12[which(unlist(list.12) %in% "Group1")], "Group1")
Map(`[`, list.12[which(unlist(list.12) %in% "Group1")], list4_ind)
[[1]]
[1] "Group1"
```

Like option 1, this returns only the matching element

Benchmarks for list-options:

```
Unit: microseconds
       expr    min     lq     mean  median     uq      max neval
 list_opt_1 37.837 38.943  48.4543 46.3615 48.831   85.498    10
 list_opt_2  8.474  9.749 243.2209 11.2840 12.538 2330.869    10
 list_opt_3  3.384  3.876   4.9735  4.2705  5.051   11.233    10
 list_opt_4 22.056 22.209  27.1948 25.8670 29.827   36.355    10
```

Output for list.34 for all the options that output a list:

**Options 1 & 4**:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Group1" "Group1"
```

**Options 2 & 3** (actually, option 2 does not return an empty second element to the list, only list1):

```
[[1]]
   [1] "Group1"    "Group2"    "Group3"    "Group4"    "Group5"    "Group6"   
   [7] "Group7"    "Group8"    "Group9"    "Group10"   "Group11"   "Group12"  
  [13] "Group13"   "Group14"   "Group15"   "Group16"   "Group17"   "Group18"
  ..........
  [985] "Group985"  "Group986"  "Group987"  "Group988"  "Group989"  "Group990" 
  [991] "Group991"  "Group992"  "Group993"  "Group994"  "Group995"  "Group996" 
  [997] "Group997"  "Group998"  "Group999"  "Group1000"
  [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 199000 entries ]

[[2]]
NULL
```

Once again, returning the entire vector that contains the match.

And benchmarks:

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
 list_opt_1 120.899425 121.931426 128.245115 130.018640 131.247377 136.823413    10
 list_opt_2   1.365003   2.398965   3.554334   2.499366   2.560078   9.524567    10
 list_opt_3  11.169013  11.987195  16.755645  15.267181  21.299495  24.538944    10
 list_opt_4  27.388212  32.125164  40.104322  40.680335  47.248335  48.679709    10
```

### Summary:

- If you want to return a vector of the exact (safe) pattern without regex, then safe option 1 seemed to scale the best.
- If you want to return a vector using regex, safe option 3 scaled best for more data. It is the same as regular option 2.
- If you want a list with only the match returned, go with list option 4.
- If you want a list with only the match by using regex, go with list option 1.
- If you want to return the vector that contains the match *within* the list, `Filter` in list option 2 is very fast.

Comment: This a super valuable answer as it highlights the risk of getting false matches I haven't seen. Thanks a lot @Andrew! There seems to be one tiny flaw in list option 3 - if I run it on list.all `list.all[which(unlist(list.all) %in% "Group1")]` it only returns the first vector: `[[1]]
[1] "Group1" "Group2" "Group3"

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL` 

I'm not sure how to subset a list with an unlisted index. Any ideas?

Comment: A very good point--I need to update my answer b/c that does not work as advertised. Don't know how that slipped through! I was meaning to update it to include `rapply` as well. Anyway, @AgileBean, what is the output you were looking for? Do you want the element of `list.all` that contains `"Group1"` or just the match(es)?

Comment: Dear @Andrew, originally I only wanted the matches but didn't know how to convert that unlist(list.all) so it can find the list entries. But having seen your interesting examples with list.all, I also wanted to get a way to retrieve the index information of which(unlist(list.all)), only translated to the index within the lists.